Type "ErrorDetails" is missing in Microsoft.Graph / Graph.Core after upgrade
I have upgraded a C#/net microsoft graph application to use the latest versions of Microsoft.Graph (version 5.52.0) and Microsoft.Graph.Core (3.1.11).
Since then I had to change many references from "Microsoft.Graph" to "Microsoft.Graph.Models". So far so good.
The problem is now: the type "ErrorDetail" is missing.
using Microsoft.Graph;
using grph = Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using grphMdls = Microsoft.Graph.Models;

....
public grph.ErrorDetail error = null;
....
public grphMdls.ErrorDetail error = null;
....

In VS I get the compile errors:
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'ErrorDetail' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Graph'
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'ErrorDetail' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Graph.Core'

Info: the previous versions I used were 4.48.0.0 for Microsoft.Graph and
2.0.14.0 for Microsoft.Graph.Core.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance
Peter
Changing the reference from "Microsoft.Graph" to "Microsoft.Graph.Models" produces the same result.

It shall be Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ErrorDetails. More details can be seen in Github.
I also checked it in my codes, this is ErrorDetail in V4

And this is for V5


Thank you for your help.
In the meantime I implemented a workaround by grabbing a source file "errorDetail.cs" from MS source server and modifying it for my environment. Modifying in this case means changing the Json property attributes to Newtonsoft format. (The original uses System.Text.Json.Serialization.)
But I will come back to your suggestions during the next major update of the program.
